# Can I stack Interfaces?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have a Furnace connected to my AE network using an ME Interface. This interface contains the maximum amount of Encoded Patterns it can hold. If I wanted to introduce additional patterns for my furnace to craft would I need to make a second Furnace and a second ME Interface or could I simply make only a second Interface and attach it to the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no but you can use a vanilla hopper that has multiple interfaces pushing stuff into it and funnels it down to the furnace

you can even stack them

Comment: I'm not quite following your design here, can you elaborate? you mean setting up X interfaces all connected to a hopper which is connected to the furnace?

Comment: @Ender Exactly, the Interface doesn't understand the machine—all it knows is that if it puts stuff in, it gets stuff out. A hopper is the same as a furnace as far as the Interface is concerned, as long as putting stuff in results in the right output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stack them to the same furnace. Even if you could, the setting would not be optimized as having multiple furnaces for different recipe would help paralleling the cooking.

Since you need, in all the case, need a new interface, the cost of any furnace should not really be a problem (unless you are dealing with multi-block structure).